# Error: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, android-virtual-device

When executing the command "ionic cordova run android" it presents the next error:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/usuario/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator

Error: avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.init(AvdManagerCli.java:278)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:210)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
```

Comment: does the application run with `ionic serve`?

Comment: not, ionic cordova run android!

Comment: Yes, I understand that&#39;s what you are trying to do, but is there an error when you run `ionic serve`?

Answer (score 2):

First you can check if it's working when you pre-launch the emulator before running "ionic cordova run android". You can either pre-launch the emulator using your Android Studio, or

```
emulator -avd your_avd_name
```

You can check to see what avd_name you have by running

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Now I assume can run with a pre-launch emulator.

Check your file yourApp/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js

You likely will see some code like this:

```
return superspawn.spawn('avdmanager', ['list', 'avd'])
```

This means cordova will try to invoke "avdmanager list avd". You can run this same command to see the same error. In my case, I see the same error when just running "avdmanager". Somehow my Android SDK Tools was corrupted. I just remove and reinstall it from Android Studio and things start working again.

Good luck!

Comment: What if you are using the Android command line tools without Android Studio?

Comment: I had the same problem but was not using cordova, only the Android command line tools. I fixed it by deleting the tools/ directory and re-extracting the command line tools into the android-sdk folder.